# SwiftUI: Get Element at Specific Index Position?

Tags: arrays, loops, swiftui, position

I want to get the object at a specific position in an array I fetched from database. I am natively an Android app developer and transitioning to iOS development while trying methods like

`int position = 0;`

`int object = preparedArray.index(position);`

How do I get this equivalence in SwiftUI?
All solutions I see are getting index of occurrences but I want to get objects at specific int index.

Comment: have a look at this info: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html
    it will answer your question in full.  Read also the basics at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's exactly what you're trying to achieve, but this could help.

```
var preparedArray: [String] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
var position: Int = 1

print(preparedArray[position])
```

This prints out `b` as it's an element of the array with the index 1.